# Animate cell.imageview on async load

Tags: ios, swift, animation, race-condition

Im trying to do a table where the imageView on the cell changes alpha from 0 to 1 when the image is done loading (async).
What ever I do it seem that the image is just shown at one and not fading in. I'm sure it's some kind of race condition but I am new to animations in iOS and have no idea how to solve this. Any input would be great. 
Here is my code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

    //Configure the cell...
    let episode = episodes[indexPath.row]

    cell.textLabel?.text = episode.title

    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = episode.content

    let logoUrl = URL(string: episode.logoUrl!)

    if (episode.logoImage == nil){
        episode.logoImage = UIImage()
        DispatchQueue.global().async {
            let data = try? Data(contentsOf: logoUrl!) //make sure your image in this url does exist, otherwise unwrap in a if let check / try-catch
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                episode.logoImage = UIImage(data: data!)
                cell.imageView?.image = episode.logoImage
                self.episodesTable.reloadData()
                cell.imageView?.alpha = 0
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations: {
                    cell.imageView?.alpha = 1
                })

            }
        }
    } else{
        cell.imageView?.image = episode.logoImage
    }

    return cell
}
```

Comment: Is the `self.episodesTable.reloadData()` needed? Try removing it maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`reloadData()` call is causing reloading of all the cells including the one you are trying to animate. My advice is to mark your cell with it's index path. After async call check if it is still presenting the right data and animate it without reloading the whole table view.

```
// ...
cell.tag = indexPath.item
DispatchQueue.global().async {
    // async load
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        guard cell.tag == indexPath.item else { return }
        cell.imageView?.alpha = 0.0
        cell.imageView?.image = image
        // animate
    }
}
// ...
```

Comment: You're right. Reload was causing the issue. Also I created a custom cell and  animated a UIImage on that instead of using the default cell image.

Answer (score 3):

You need to set alpha to 0 first before animating to 1.

```
cell.imageView?.alpha = 0
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations: {
                    cell.imageView?.alpha = 1
                })
```

Also, you dont need to reload table. Remove `self.episodesTable.reloadData()`.

You are spanning a background thread and loading the image from url inside that thread. What if, in between user has scrolled the cell. You would be left with a wrong image on a wrong cell(because of cell reuse, that is).

My advice is to use [SDWebImageCache](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage), and use its completion block to animate the alpha.

```
// Changing animation duration to 0.2 seconds from 1 second 
if(cacheType == SDImageCacheTypeNone) {
    cell.imageView?.alpha = 0
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{ 
        cell.imageView?.alpha = 1;
    }];
}
```

Comment: You are absolutely right. However that was in my code all ready, not sure how it got lost it in this question. But this does not solve the problem the images still does not fade in, the just appear. I fixed the question with the missing line.